# SQL check if record value exists, one SQL statement, no specific SQL features

Tags: sql

The similar question is asked several times, but the answers are either specific to SQL server (SELECT TOP 1...) or not efficient (SELECT 1 FROM..., SELECT Count(*) FROM... ). I use this form:

```
SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Number1 = 1)
```

Can I say that this is the most efficient way suitable for the most SQL servers?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should be able to get away with just `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Number1 = 1)` and it should work on most database engines.

Comment: Thanks! This is shorter and I think more efficient version

Comment: Doesn't most dbms products want a `FROM` clause? At least ANSI SQL require it.

Comment: @jarlh - I tested it on MySQL, SQL Server and SQLite. Impossible to really test on every single database software out there. OP needs to be specific about what database he is using so I can construct one suited for that engine.

Comment: @Icemanind  Sorry buddy, it doesn't work with Firebird

Comment: And not with Oracle. And I'm having doubts with SQL Server, at least version 2014.

Comment: And not with SQL Server 2008

Comment: Most applications have a single database as a backend. Why are you needed SQL statements that work on multiple database engines?

Comment: My app supports firebird and ms sql - the customer's requirement